# How to declare namespaces at one place in marklogic and then import/invoke them in various xquery files?

Tags: xquery, marklogic, xml-namespaces

I have more than 50 namespaces used in my Marklogic API's .The count can go on increasing further - I am looking for a way to find the feasibility if there is any way to utilise or store them in database or add them in app-server and later on how to invoke them in all the Xquery files- where they have been till now are updated manually in case of any new addition.

Answer (score 4):

Yes! If you go to the Admin API (port 8001) and go under either your Group or App Servers, you'll see a Namespaces section on the left and in there you can enter your commonly used namespaces. After that they'll just exist in all the code automatically.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response!! Just need to ask if once these are added in the admin app server after then do I need to make some reference in the code or they will work automatically?

Comment: I tried adding the namespace in the appserver namespace tab but still the code din't worked automatically however when I declared the same namespaces in the Groups headed namespaces it worked- any help on this if want to achieve this using App-server?

Comment: You'd have to add it to the app server on the port you're hitting.

Comment: Putting them at group level is probably more convenient. That way they are know in QConsole as well, for instance, and in the TaskServer too.